# Fastest way to convert Character to uppercase or lowercase in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, unicode, swift4

I understand the reasons why the `Character` class doesn't support `toUpper()` and `toLower()` but my use case is not for language purposes.  Furthermore, I do not wish to revert to `NSString`.

So what's the fastest way to convert a character to upper case or lower case using Swift 4?

```
// Is there something better than this?
extension Character {
    func toLower() -> Character {
        return String(self).lowercased().first!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `uppercase2()` below if you only need to uppercase the first char. It’s a 5x speed up over uppercasing the entire string.

```
import Foundation

// too slow, maybe with some bitwise operations could get faster ‍♀️
func uppercase(_ string: String) -> Character? {
    let key: Int8 = string.utf8CString[0]
    guard key>0, key<127, let c = Unicode.Scalar(Int(key >= 97 ? key - Int8(32) : key)) else { return nil }
    return Character(c)
}

// winner but using internal _core stuff
func uppercase2(_ string: String) -> Character? {
    guard let key = string._core.asciiBuffer?[0] else { return nil }
    return Character(Unicode.Scalar(key >= 97 ? key - 32 : key)) // use < + to lowercase
}

func measure(times: Int, task: ()->()){
    let start1 = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 1..<times {
        task()
    }
    print(CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start1)
}

print("".uppercased().first as Any) // Optional("")
print(uppercase("") as Any) // nil
print(uppercase2("") as Any) // nil

measure(times: 10_000_000) { _ = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".uppercased().first } // 4.17883902788162
measure(times: 10_000_000) { _ = uppercase("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") }         // 4.91275697946548
measure(times: 10_000_000) { _ = uppercase2("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ") }        // 0.720575034618378
```

---

In a 10 million run, Apple’s `uppercased` ran 148x times faster than the code at the bottom of this post, even with force-unwrap. I’ll leave it for comedic purposes.

Their approach is of course, way lower level. See [lowercased()](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L1149). They check for an internal asciiBuffer and then use an [_asciiUpperCaseTable](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L1130).

My understanding is that if the original String is already a Swift String, it will be represented by a [StringCore](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a05cd35a7f8e3cc70e0666bc34b5056a543eafd4/stdlib/public/core/StringCore.swift) class which is already optimized to deal with ASCII characters at a low level. Thus, you won’t be able to beat the uppercase function of Swift.

So, kind of an answer: the fastest way is to use the regular `uppercase()` function.

---

I'm assuming that “my use-case is not for language purposes” means I’m only using ASCII. The advantage that this provides is that UTF-8 and ASCII share the same scalar code, so upper/lowercasing implies subtracting or adding a fixed number.

```
import Foundation

print("a".unicodeScalars.first!.value) // 97 
print("A".unicodeScalars.first!.value) // 65

let uppercase = String("abcde".flatMap { 
    guard let char = $0.unicodeScalars.first, 
          let uppercased = Unicode.Scalar(char.value - UInt32(97 - 65)) 
    else {
        return nil
    }
    return Character(uppercased)
})

print(uppercase) // ABCDE
```

Comment: Thanks for your awesome, detailed answer and secondly, it made me aware that I could look at their source code for the String class.  In my case, I am getting the first character of an ASCII string and forcing it to either lower or upper case for use as a key in a dictionary.  I could run lowercased() on the entire string and get the first character but would using a subset of your code be any better?

Comment: See uppercase2 for 6x speed over uppercasing the entire string. Still brrrrrr there has to be many ways to improve that code, I just don’t know how at the moment.